# Where are the scan settings stored on ce 5.0 MC9090? They are not in the registry that I can see

Tags: windows-ce, motorola

We are using MC9090's running CE 5.0.  We are using a program called Wavelink Studio Client to access our scan application.  Studio Client is different and not the same as Wavelink Telnet CE.  Wavelink Studio is only a "Go Between" and does not hold any settings.  The Wavelink Studio basically looks at the scanner .dll and pulls settings from that.

My problem is that I have an Interleaved 2 of 5 barcode with 16 length.  The MC9090 comes with two demo programs ScanWedge and ScanSamp.  I can modify the length for int 2 of 5 in either of these programs and my barcode will scan through Wavelink Studio Client.  However, after a warm boot I lose all my settings since these are just demo programs.

So, I turned to DataWedge.  Which uses its own config folder to store settings, but I assume loads the settings into the scanner .dll.  My barcode scans perfectly in Studio Client when DataWedge is installed only after the DataWedge process has been "Stopped" then "Started".  If perform a warm boot and DataWedge starts... my barcode will not scan through studio client until DataWedge has been Stopped, then my barcode will scan through Studio Client whether DataWedge is Started or Stopped.

My question is:  Is there a script/command line/bat/etc.  that I could use that would "Stop" DataWedge, then "Start" DataWedge after a warm boot?  This is one way to solve my problem.

If anyone has any other suggestions, please let me know.  I have repeatedly been told that the settings from ScanSamp and ScanWedge (demo apps) are not stored anywhere on the device.  I believe they are stored somewhere though. Because, when I make a change on DataWedge, I can open ScanWedge and the settings happen there to.  So there must be some central location where the hard scan settings are stored?  I just need to be able to edit the settings in this location and have them stay there.  I don't even need DataWedge if the scanner would hold the settings in the .dll that I specify from ScanWedge.  With datawedge uninstalled, I tried changing my settings in ScanWedge then using RemCapture to capture all the settings from the device.. I then loaded those settings onto another device to see if it would load the scan settings, but it did not.

Answer (score 1):

Set the options in ScanWedge. Then Use "Remote Registry Editor" that comes with Visual Studio 2008 and go to this path: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Symbol\ScanWedge]

There you will see the various settings for ScanWedge. To persist these settings over warm & cold boot do the following:

1. Open Notepad on the PC.
   Type the following registry entry:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Symbol\ScanWedge]

"AutoEnter"=dword:00000000

"AutoPIE"=dword:00000000

"AutoTab"=dword:00000000

"Binary"=dword:00000000

"Data"=dword:00000001

"Escape"=dword:00000001

"Prefix"=""
"Suffix"=""

Save the file as scanwedge.reg
Place the file on your Terminal in the \Application Folder using ActiveSync.
Cold boot the terminal.
NOTE:  A cold reboot will erase all files, except the application and platform folder.  Save your files before cold booting.

Hope this helps.